# Qual é a origem da expressão «bicho-carpinteiro»?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Estava a ler uma [publicação](https://twitter.com/_Goalpoint/status/1711133660575932627?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1711133660575932627%7Ctwgr%5E7799744339f5a09afb4d18bf02317b3b10f0da83%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoalpoint.pt%2Fsporting-arouca-primeira-liga-202324_177400) em que se usa a expressão «bicho-carpinteiro», no sentido de dizer que o jogador de futebol não para quieto. Usa-se muito essa expressão para crianças que não param quietas, exemplo:

> Este moço não para quieto, parece que tem «bichos-carpinteiros»!

Numa [resposta à publicação](https://twitter.com/Nove_9_IX/status/1711271440169816501) o utilizador dá a entender que a expressão está errada e que deriva de outra «parece que tem bichos pelo corpo inteiro». Que também parece ser uma possibilidade.

Então fiquei a pensar qual seria a origem desta expressão. O autor da publicação sugere uma [pergunta do ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-expressao-estar-com-bicho-carpinteiro/21820) mas não esclareceu a situação.

Então qual é a origem da expressão «bicho-carpinteiro»?

Answer (score 1):

A primeira vez que eu encontrei essa expressão foi num livro de 1787, [«Théatro comico portuguez»](https://www.google.pt/books/edition/Th%C3%A9atro_comico_portuguez/_kNEAAAAcAAJ?hl=pt-PT&gbpv=1&dq=bicho%20carpinteiro&pg=PA176&printsec=frontcover) de Antonio José da SILVA.

Aparece já num dicionário em 1881, [«Diccionario contemporaneo da lingua portugueza»](https://www.google.pt/books/edition/Diccionario_contemporaneo_da_lingua_port/KUyTkwQ7SnAC?hl=pt-PT&gbpv=1&dq=bicho%20carpinteiro&pg=PA291&printsec=frontcover) com a definição "não pode estar socegado em um logar" como se pode ver na imagem.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Embora não dê para concluir qual a sua origem exata dá pelo menos para concluir que a expressão vem mesmo de «bicho carpinteiro» que já era usada no século XVIII.